# Subtract two DataFrames with non overlapping indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract two DataFrames together. I would like to treat missing values as 0. `fillna()` won't work here because I don't know the common indexes before doing the subtraction:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame([1,2], index=['a','b'])
B = pd.DataFrame([3,4], index=['a','c'])
A - B

    0
a  -2
b NaN
c NaN
```

Ideally, I would like to have:

```
A - B

    0
a  -2
b   2
c  -4
```

Is it possible to get that while keeping the code simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `subtract` method and specify a `fill_value` of zero:

```
A.subtract(B, fill_value=0)
```

---

*Note: the method below, `combineAdd`, [is deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10812) from 0.17.0 onwards*.

One way is to use the `combineAdd` method to add `-B` to `A`:

```
>>> A.combineAdd(-B)
   0
a -2
b  2
c -4
```

With this method, the two DataFrames are added and the values at non-matching indices default to the value in either `A` or `B`.